# Why is there no "return if" statement in programming languages?

Tags: if-statement, return, programming-languages

First of all, I would like to point out that my theoretical knowledge of the anatomy of programming languages is not as deep as it should be, and I apologize in advance.

This may also be a stupid question, I apologize for that, but I have been wondering for some time why there is no `return if` statement or at least syntactic sugar for it in (at least the ones I'm familiar with) programming languages, especially in languages like Python or Lua, which are relatively high-level and often allow an alternative spelling with syntactic sugar.

Take the following code, for example:

```
if(x > y) {
    return x;
}
```

Of course you know directly what happens, `if x > y is true x is returned`.
However, one could now argue the following:

1. Depending on the programming language several lines are needed for a simple statement. *Of course you could write it inline like `if (x > y) { return x }`*
2. It doesn't "sound" that great: `if x > y, x gets returned`

*Just to make it clear, I don't mean to say that the "traditional" way is bad, I'm just asking out of interest.*

If you were to use a statement like "return if", the above statement could look like this:

```
return x if (x > y);
```

It is a one-liner and it reads well `x gets returned if x > y`

---

Now I asked myself the following questions:

1. Is this simply a design decision?
2. Does a `return if` syntax cause unnecessary complications for the parser/compiler?
3. If it's neither the first nor the second, then what is it? Coincidence? I will certainly not be the first one to think about it in all the decades of programming.

**Edit**: 
Since my example was apparently misleading, what I mean is the same behavior with different syntax.

So `return x if(x > y)` does not return at all if x is not greater than y.

Comment: Programming language implementations are strongly biased towards top-down, left-right evaluation (like the English language).  Your suggestion to place the `x>y` at after the `return x` cuts against that grain.  There's no reason a programming language couldn't implement that approach to `if` statements, but I suspect that the compiler would issue instructions to evaluate the condition first, followed by a jump.

Comment: There are languages (e.g. Perl) that have conditional suffixes, permitting '<statement> if <condition>' but in general there seems little point. You may prefer to say "do somerhing if condition" but others prefer 'if condition do something'.  The important part is that it can be said at all; the code emitted will be the same in both cases.

Comment: This would make programming and code reviews much more annoying because the if block could be very large and I don't like reading code first to only find out that the code was not executed right at the end. If I can read the condition first then I know I can skip reading the code that gets executed next. Also, having the condition first is respecting the sequence of execution which makes more logical sense to me when reading the code. I don't see any benefit in reversing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some programming languages have (my words) a conditional suffix.

You can say in Perl, for example:

```
    print "I don't mind" if 6 == 9
```

This construction of course can be used specifically for

```
    return "I don't mind" if 6 == 9
```

So the premise is not true in general.  In particular cases, it's because the language designer saw no value in it. As one comment said, the general disposition is to left-to-right parsing.  Adding this sort of syntax looks to me (a mere amateur in language design) like adding complexity for little benefit.

Note that in the construction "*statement* if *condition*" then *statement* can be arbitrarily complicated, e.g. many lines enclosed in { }.  That's not too readable.

Answer (score 0):

The question as I understand it boils down to: Why are conditional statements left aligned in most syntaxes. That is: (cond value) instead of (value cond). 
The argument for the latter was, that it follows natural language syntax more closely. While that may be the case syntactically semantically the opposite seems more natural:
You first list the condition that has to be met, since everything following (the subtree) might not even have to be evaluated and in context of the program can be seen as meaningless.